# In VS Code, how can I run the active python file in active terminal while running another python script?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have couple of scripts I need to run simultaneously. One of them is a long-run script which is currently running and another script is a new script which is in development mode so I need to run it multiple times but I want to do this using <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> keys for convenience.

Currently, when I hit <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd>, I get switched to the previous terminal where the long-run script is running and nothing happens after, however I have already created a new terminal window and activated the new environment in which I am developing the new script... The only way I can run that new script in new terminal is writing the command in terminal which is inconvenient and takes more time than just hitting <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd>. Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, as user mentioned, is to create multiple terminals and run your Python files separately on each terminal by command `python filename.py`.

You can also try to use [jupyter-notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) or [python interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py).

You can run the required Python scripts separately in different `.ipynb` files.

Comment: Thank you, will stick to interactive window or launch a long-run script with windows terminal

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I can run that new script in new terminal is writing the command in terminal which is inconvenient

Workaround: Take a look at the `File: Copy Relative Path of Active File` command and see what keybinding it's bound to. You can use that to copy the relative path and then paste into your terminal.

> One of them is a long-run script which is currently running

I'd suggest just running that long-running one in its own terminal. You can have multiple VS Code integrated terminals open at a time. See the "+" button.

> another script is a new script which is in developement mode so I need to run it multiple times

Actually. a lot of shells have history features built in (Ex. [Bash's Readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Searching.html), [PowerShell's PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline?view=powershell-7.3), etc.). You can probably just press the up and down arrow keys to navigate between previously-run commands in your shell, and then press enter to run one again.

For the record, here's my answer to the actual question here: I don't know of any way to get exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For linux or gitbash terminals, you can also run your long running script as a background process in the shell.

```
python3 myscript.py &
```

More details: [how-to-run-linux-commands-in-background](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-background/)