# run python shift+enter shortcut in other terminal while the main terminal is running in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, pid

i tried to find a way to run python shift+enter shortcut in other terminal  while the main terminal is running in visual studio code

First off.Im self learning and my experience is quite low.Im still not sure what terminal and what shell is.

And by terminal i mean the one that next to debug console.Im very confuse why the switch terminal shortcut is just switch each open file tab.

Here what i want to do.let say i run this python code in visual studio code and this code take a really really long time to finish.more than 24 hrs.

While i wait for the process to finish i want to open other python terminal where i can conveniently test any python code by highlight the code and press shift+enter for shortcut because i always screw up my code and have to test and fix it over and over.

but it seem the shortcut is bind to the previous terminal so when i use shortcut it send to that terminal which not finish its very long process yet.

I can copy and paste the code in new terminal myself but it slow me down.

I see that each of this terminal have their own process id.I have google for 2 hrs now and can't figure out

and my "python:attach using id" is keep searching forever and don't show anything.it still going on

Comment: why run the 24h python script in a VSC terminal, just open a terminal OUTSIDE VSC and start the long running code there, you can kill/restart VSC whenever you want

Comment: what i want to do is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995563/how-can-i-force-vs-code-to-run-python-processes-in-a-fresh-terminal

Comment: a terminal is a program that shows the input/output (stdin/stdout/stderr) from a shell process to the screen or socket (remote connection) and reads the keyboard and sends it to the shell

Comment: do these terminals stay alive when you kill VSC, or are they child processes of VSC

Comment: rioV8 it child processes of vsc. it easier to read and locate since it alway show in the visual studio and i can split panel anyway i want.Also if i run outside vsc i have to declare where the folder i want to import my custom py file is.But if there no way to achieve this then i guess outside terminal is best option available

Comment: for that there is the shell command `cd` to move to the directory with the script, or give the full path of the script when calling python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In VS Code, how can I run the active python file in active terminal while running another python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030649/in-vs-code-how-can-i-run-the-active-python-file-in-active-terminal-while-runnin)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter).

One way is to create `.ipynb` file and use run cell button to keep this file running for a long time.

[image]

You can also use Interactive window which is the same as using jupyter in `.py` file.
[image]

Of course, there exists another simplest method, because the terminal used in VsCode is an existing terminal in your PC system. For example, you can directly use `Win + R` and input `cmd` to run your python file in `cmd` directly.